# What level of normalization is this relation

Tags: database, database-normalization

A movie has one and only one genre.

A genre can be assigned to many movies.

Movies(MovieName,  Genre)

MovieName is the only key

MovieName->Genre is the only determinant

Answer (score 0):

If `MovieName` is the key, and the only *dependence* (not the only determinant!) is:

```
MovieName → Genre
```

then the relation is in First, Second, and Third Normal Form, as well as in Boyce-Codd Normal Form, and also in higher level forms (for instance Fourth Normal Form).

This is because in the (unique) dependency the determinant (`MovieName`) is the key, so all the definition of normal forms are respected.

Comment: That "because" only guarantees BCNF.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really mean "What level of normalization is this relation [in]". A relation variable or value can be in lots of normal forms at once. When it's in one, it's in all the lower ones, and it could be in higher ones. So presumably what you mean is "What is the highest level of normalization this relation must be in".

MovieName->Genre is not a determinant. It is a FD (functional dependency). Its determinant is {MovieName}. That is the only determinant of a CK (candidate key). The non-trivial FDs are
 {MovieName}->{Genre}
 {MovieName}->{MovieName,Genre}
Since every determinant of a non-trivial FD is a superkey, this is in BCNF. Since it's in BCNF, it's in every lower normal form.

There are two theorems by Date & Fagin relevant here:

- if a relation is in 3NF (or BCNF) and every CK is simple, then it is in 5NF
- if a relation is in BCNF and some CK is simple, then it is in 4NF

Since your relation is in BCNF it is 3NF and since every CK is simple it is in 5NF.

---

PS What if we didn't know these theorems?

If the only constraints on this value/variable were the ones implied by what you gave then it is in 5NF. Because by definition it's in 5NF when it doesn't satisfy any JDs (join dependencies) other than those that are implied by its having that set of candidate keys.

But if all we knew about the value/variable is what you gave then how could we show that it still must be in 5NF?

If the JD *{{MovieName},{Genre}} also held then it wouldn't be in 4NF (or higher). Ie if it were also equal to the join of its projections on {MovieName} & {Genre}. In the join/original every input MovieName value would be in a tuple with every Genre value. The CK says there is only one such pair per MovieName. So there would only be one Genre value in the input. Then FK {} -> {Genre} would hold. BCNF implies 2NF, which says there are no partial dependencies on CKs, so FK {} -> {Genre} doesn't hold. So we have a contradiction re it holding. So the JD doesn't hold. So the relation is in 4NF because there are no other non-trivial binary JDs that could hold to violate 4NF. It is also in 5NF because there are no JDs with more than two elements that could hold.